# Differences between values within two lists in Haskell with List Comprehension

Tags: haskell

I'm making a function in Haskell to compute the differences between values in two lists.

For example, I have two lists:

```
    List A = [1,2,3]
    List B = [2,3,4]
```

Subtract the first element of A with the first element of B, subtract the second element of A with the second element of B, and so on. The result should be like this:

```
    Result = [-1,-1,-1]
```

How to make this function? I tried using this but failed:

```
diff xs ys = [i-j | i <- xs, j <- ys, length xs == length ys]
```

And the result of using that wrong function is (I used list A and list B, look above):

```
    [-1,-2,-3,0,-1,-2,1,0,-1]
```

Someone told me that i <- xs, j <- ys means cross-joining the elements of xs and ys, so the result is like this:

```
    [(1-2),(1-3),(1-4),(2-2),(2-3),(2-4),(3-2),(3-3),(3-4)
```

Using list comprehension, and without using `i <- xs, j <- ys`, complete this function:

```
diff :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
diff [] [] = []
diff xs [] = []
diff [] ys = []
```

Comment: is this a exercise or why do you have to use list-comprehensions? the ususal way is just `diff xs ys =  zipWith (-) xs ys`

Comment: also your last part looks like you just want to add `diff (x:xs) (y:ys) = ...` as the last case ... this should be really easy for you to do (no list comprehension needed - recursion might be a good idea though)

Comment: Probably the intended solution starts with `zip xs ys` and continues with a list comprehension to achieve the same effect of `zipWith`.

Comment: are you allowed to use `zip`, are you supposed to implement the function with pattern matching (the part you started last)

Comment: i can use zip... I'm planning to use the pattern matching but I need to use list comprehension so I don't think I can use the pattern matching code i made...

Comment: go with the hint @chi gave you then ;) (`diff xs ys = [ x-y | ? <- zip ? ? ]`)

Comment: `diff xs ys [x-y | (x,y) <- zip xs ys]` worked! Thank you!

Comment: If you enable the parallel list comprehensions extension, you can write `[x-y | x <- xs | y <- ys]`. This is just a syntactic sugar for the `zip` thing.

Comment: maybe you should wait with this till you understand the *vanilla* comprehensions better ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you like list comprehensions, you can use [an extension](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/list-comprehension-extensions):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}

diff a b = [p - q | p <- a | q <- b]
```

which is internally translated into `zip`.

Answer (score 1):

```
diff :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
diff a b = map (\(p, q) -> p - q) $ zip a b
```

Comment: it's just a compressed version of yours